# i want all the first name under first_name column and all the last names under last_name column and all the telephone under Telephone column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

The person-wise data received is as under -

[image]

so on........

And i want that there should be Three columns - First_name, Last_name, Telephone and all the first names should come under First_name column in different rows and so on like below-

[image]

so that the analysis can be easy.

Help me out to do this in excel

I tried to do it with Transpose but couldn't get the desired results.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way of doing it:

[image]

---

```
=VSTACK(UNIQUE(TOROW(A:A,1),1),WRAPROWS(TOCOL(B:B,1),3))
```

---

Using `POWER QUERY` I will do in this way:

[image]

---

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    RemovedBlanks = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Header_2] <> null and [Header_2] <> ""),
    Group = Table.Group(RemovedBlanks, {"Header_1"}, {{"Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),type table}}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Group, "Custom", {"Header_2", "Index"}, {"Header_2", "Index"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded Custom", List.Distinct(#"Expanded Custom"[Header_1]), "Header_1", "Header_2"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Another alternative `POWER QUERY` method:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Filtered = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Header_1] <> null and [Header_1] <> ""),
    ColNames = Table.Distinct(Table.SelectColumns(Filtered,{"Header_1"}))[Header_1],
    Answer = Table.FromRows(List.Split(Table.SelectColumns(Filtered,{"Header_2"})[Header_2],3),ColNames)
in
    Answer
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula B1:B15 the range of the data.

```
=VSTACK({"First name","Last name","Telephone"},TAKE(WRAPROWS(B1:B15,4),,3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In powerquery you could also use an index instead of a group

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Header_1] <> null)),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Integer-Divided Column" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index", {{"Index", each Number.IntegerDivide(_, 3), Int64.Type}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Integer-Divided Column", List.Distinct(#"Integer-Divided Column"[Header_1]), "Header_1", "Header_2")
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

Answer (score 0):

because you have not defined the table output, assuming you have all data in one column, so you can use "Text to Columns" in "Data" tab in Excel option separate category. Select the entire column, then Delimited, Taband Space, then General and click Finish. Once the names is separated and then you can name it accordingly

[image]